# stop refreshing a servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I know I can use method `response.setIntHeader("Refresh", 3);` to refresh a servlet every 3 seconds but how can I stop refreshing it once certain conditions in my web application are met ? e.g. my servlet refreshes every 3 sec, I have the above code statement declared in my `doGet()` method but once I change String value then prevent it from that refresh ? Is that even possible ?

```
String value = "whatever";

if(value.equals("whatever")){
// stop refreshing the page 
}
```

Comment: You could remove the header...

Comment: You can simply set it to response.setIntHeader("Refresh", Integer.MAX_VALUE) or response.setIntHeader("Refresh", 0) ?

Comment: @joh.scheuer setting it to 0 generates a redirect, as explained here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh

Comment: @Luggi thanks! Thats true, was a fallacy of myself :). But inserting a negative number should also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below solution should work.

```
String value = "whatever";
boolean isServletNeedRefresh = true;

if(value.equals("whatever")){
   // stop refreshing the page 
   isServletNeedRefresh = false;
}

if (isServletNeedRefresh)
{
    response.setIntHeader("Refresh", 3); 
}
```

Comment: Or easier: `if(!value.equals("whatever")){ response.setIntHeader("Refresh", 3); }`

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza very true.